# Plotly - Use custom Font

Tags: python, fonts, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to use a custom installed font in Plotly, specifically Plotly Express, however my fonts do not seem to be recognized by Plotly.

My font is being recognized by Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import Tk, font
root = Tk()
print(font.families())
```

Output:

```
 ('System', 'Terminal', 'Fixedsys', 'Modern', 'Roman', 'Script', 'Courier', 'MS Serif', ..., 
  '**HaboroSans-NormRegular**', ...)
```

However: When I try to use this font in Plotly:

```
px.line(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3], title = 'Plot 123').update_layout(titlefont_family = 'HaboroSans-NormRegular')
```

I get a graph returned with the default plotly font.

Any Ideas?

Comment: There is one underscore missing, it should be `title_font_family`.